# LEAD in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I have done a stored procedure with contains LEAD, unfortunately the script must run on 2008, so anyone know how to achieve this in 2008?

```
INSERT INTO #ARTICLES(EAN, ID_ART, QTE, PV_NET_HT)
SELECT EAN, ID_ART, QTE_CDE, PA_NET
FROM (
    SELECT TEXTE_LIG,
            CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN ID_ART ELSE LEAD(ID_ART) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) END AS ID_ART,
            CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN CHAR01 ELSE LEAD(CHAR01) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) END AS EAN,
            LEAD(QTE_CDE, CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS QTE_CDE,
            LEAD(PX_BASE, CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PX_BASE,
            LEAD(PX_NET, CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PA_NET
    FROM AMAZON_ACHATS_LIG 
    WHERE ID_ACHATS_ENT = @IDENTITY
) AS LIGNE
WHERE TEXTE_LIG LIKE 'LIN%';
```

Comment: Prior to sql server 2012, you need to do a self join,.

Comment: Side note: `LEAD(column) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` is nonsensical. `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` means the lead window function will return an arbitrary row. (Note that arbitrary is not the same as random).

Comment: The query work fine with no order by because i don't want them to be ordered. I must do it in 2008

Comment: That is hard to read.  I am not even going to try.  Moving on.

Comment: @user1340587, if you don't want them ordered, why are you using LEAD?  That gets the 'NEXT' value, which implies order.

Comment: I don't see the purpose in the query.  That makes it very difficult to suggestion an alternative.  Please provide some business rules.  As it is right now, it appears to be if the value not like '%++%' get a value from some other unspecified record.

Comment: @WesH I want to keep the database order, tomorrow i will give the string i parse. It's right if i don't get value after '%++%' on the current row i have to take it on the next

Comment: @user1340587 Don't use ORDER BY (SELECT NULL).  Use the field you're thinking of when you determine what should be NEXT.

Comment: @WesH values cames from a bulk insert from a string. so i parse it. the rows are very differents. i will give a sample tomorrow. right now it's midnight in France.

Comment: "I want to keep the database order" There is no such thing. rows in a relational database have no order. Tables are unordered sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace LEAD in 2008, you need to do a self join to the same table, to the next row. To do this, the easiest way is to have a contiguous ID of some sort, and you can join to the record with ID + one. If no suitable contiguous ID exists, then select your data in a CTE, and add a row_number to it. Then use that row_number in the outer query for the self join.

Incidentally, be aware there is no such thing as "keeping the database order". If you don't have an order specified for a given query, then SQL will decide the output order, which may be the same order as entry, or may be something totally different, or may be mostly the same order except for a few records. It may return totally different orders for the same query on different occasions, depending on which query plan it decides to use this time. If you want data to keep the same order it was entered in, you need to have an auto-incrementing identity column to ensure that is possible, or someday you will not get what you expect.

In your query, your various leads have offsets of none (same as 1), 1, 2 and 3, so you will need to self join three times to cover all of those options. In your query, you then replace each of the LEAD with the data from the correct self-joined table. You want something like this:

```
WITH BASEDATA AS (
    --THIS IS YOUR BASIC DATA, WITH A ROW NUMBER ADDED
    -- DO THIS AS A CTE, SO YOU CAN JOIN TO IT MULTIPLE TIMES
    SELECT TEXTE_LIG, ID_ART, CHAR01, QTE_CDE, PX_BASE, PX_NET, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNo
    FROM AMAZON_ACHATS_LIG 
    WHERE ID_ACHATS_ENT = @IDENTITY
)
INSERT INTO #ARTICLES(EAN, ID_ART, QTE, PV_NET_HT)
SELECT EAN, ID_ART, QTE_CDE, PA_NET
FROM (
    SELECT TEXTE_LIG,
            CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN ID_ART ELSE B1.ID_ART END AS ID_ART,
            CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN CHAR01 ELSE B1.CHAR01 END AS EAN,
            CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN B1.QTE_CDE ELSE B2.QTE_CDE END AS QTE_CDE,
            CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN B2.PX_BASE ELSE B3.PX_BASE END AS PX_BASE,
            CASE WHEN TEXTE_LIG LIKE '%++%' THEN B2.PX_NET ELSE B3.PX_NET END AS PA_NET
    FROM BASEDATA B0  --THE BASIC DATA
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BASEDATA B1 ON B1.RowNo = B0.RowNo + 1  --This is your LEAD (1) table
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BASEDATA B2 ON B2.RowNo = B0.RowNo + 2  --This is your LEAD (2) table
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BASEDATA B3 ON B3.RowNo = B0.RowNo + 3  --This is your LEAD (3) table
    --WHERE ID_ACHATS_ENT = @IDENTITY  --DON'T NEED THIS AMY MORE, DONE IN CTE
) AS LIGNE
WHERE TEXTE_LIG LIKE 'LIN%';
```

Comment: I've commented out the no longer needed where clause in the innermost query. In fact, because that selection is done in the basedata CTE, you could now collapse the two bottom queries into one if you wanted.